# Using comparison operators in ON clause

Tags: clickhouse

Cannot use comparison operators in ON clause?

[How to reproduce]

- ClickHouse server version : v19.11.0
- Example with two tables

table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    str1 String,
    num1 UInt64
) ENGINE=MergeTree()
ORDER BY (str1);
```

table2

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
    str2 String,
    num2 UInt64
) ENGINE=MergeTree()
ORDER BY (str2);
```

query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 AS t2
ON
    t1.str1 = t2.str2
    AND greater(t1.num1, t2.num2) = 1;
```

error message

```
DB::Exception: Invalid columns in JOIN ON section. Columns num1 and num2 are from different tables..
```

Without `AND greater(t1.num1, t2.num2) = 1`, query is successful.

Comment: I think the problem is that `greater()` function does not support that. You might open bug report / FR in clickhouse repository

Comment: I added issue as feature request.https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/5736

Comment: Just in case, obviously, you can move the condition to `WHERE` clause like `SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.str1 = t2.str2 WHERE t1.num1 > t2.num2`, just pay attention on `null` handling.

Comment: just remove `= 1` behind greater(...). That should work. But thats essentially the same as using the `>` sign.    `a > b` is parsed to `greater(a, b)` by clickhouse internally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need ASOF JOIN.

> ASOF JOIN is useful when you need to join records that have no exact
> match.
>
> For example, SELECT count() FROM table_1 ASOF LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.a == table_2.b AND table_2.t <= table_1.t.

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/join/#asof-join-usage